# FTPClient - 550 permission denied

Tags: java, windows, ubuntu, ftp

i'm running java 1.7.0_21 on a windows 7 machine, and i try to delete a file on a ftp ubuntu-server. The following code snippet, shows what i do. the strange thing is, the file has the read, write and execute permission. the containing folder too. when i ask the bPermisison i receive true, but i can not delete this file....
The replyString gives the error 550 permission denied.
The same code snipped (and implementation) works fine on another ftp server. 
I searched really long, but i didn't find any hint. does somebody know what's going wrong?

Thanks for any help.

```
String sFilePath = FileUtil.concatPath(sParamRemotedir, oFTPFile.getName(), "/");            
        boolean bPermission = FTPFile.hasPermission(FTPFile.USER_ACCESS, FTPFile.WRITE_PERMISSION);
        boolean bDeleted = oFTPClient.deleteFile(sFilePath);
        sReplyString = oFTPClient.getReplyString();
        if(bRetrieveOK && !bDeleted) {
          m_oDialogError.show(ErrorText.ERROR_TRASYSTHREAD_FTPMOVE_DELETEERROR, oFTPFile.getName(), oFTPClient.getReplyString());
          bOK = false;
        }
```

Comment: Did you check your servers behaviour with a standard ftp client?

Comment: Yes i did. When i try to delete the ftp file with filezilla i can't delete it with this user. even when i login with root, no way. the conatining folder has permission 777...

Comment: So it's definitely not a Java problem. There must be a problem with your FTP server config. Please look there.

Comment: Yes! Your first question opened my eyes. i tried everitime to delete the files with putty, and this worked... clear, because putty doesn't connect over the ftp-protocol and port. Then when i tried with the ftp client (filezilla) i saw the result. the reason was.. the ftp server configuration had not the required write permissions...
Thanks a lot fot the hint. this was just the right point,

Answer (score 2):

I too had the similar problem. Once I did the following everything is fine now.

With FTP it is not sufficient be owner of files and directories. The service and daemon FTP must be correctly configured in order to write and create files etc.

In Ubuntu:
Edit **/etc/vsftpd.conf**

```
sudo gedit /etc/vsftpd.conf
```

And in the line

```
#write_enable=YES
```

Remove # in front i.e.,

```
write_enable=YES
```

Finally restart the service:(this is **very important**)

```
sudo service  vsftpd restart
```